# Is this MVC? What 'design pattern' have I used?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, model-view-controller

There's a lot of confusion over MVC but after flicking through a Head First patterns book (As a side note I hate that brand, though this example was quite good) it claims that MVC or Model View Controller is a hybrid of multiple patterns - mediator, observer etc...

In a recent prototype I did the following, it's C# but should be straightforward.

```
Person : IPerson {
    public Name { get; set;}
    public Age  { get; set;}
}
```

IPerson is just an interface defining the above - I've left it out for simplicity.

```
PersonController : IPersonController {
    public event DetailsUpdated;
    public void SetAge(int age);
    public int GetAge();
    public void SetName(string name);
    public string GetName();
}
```

I know the above could be properties themselves - but this is just  a simple example. The event is fired every time some data changes - e.g. in SetAge/SetName.

```
interface IView {
    void Initialize();
    void SetAgeClicked(object sender, EventArgs e);
    void SetNameClicked(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

Initialize wires stuff up - e.g. text boxes on the form. SetAge/SetName are the button events - so the form/page etc.. using must have these methods.

```
Form : IView {

    // IView is implemented.
    // Form is wired up
    // Initialize is set etc...
}
```

I hear the test of MVC is when you add a new view is it easy to get stuff up and running - well yes it was. However, is this MVC? Is this something else?

Any advice/input would be great. It works - it just want to know why though.

Thanks.

Comment: Yup, that's an MVC design pattern you've got there.

Comment: I have seen an opinion (and I concur) that MVC is not a design pattern, but rather an architectural pattern.

Comment: Made another prototype and it sure does fit 'Passive View' more. 
Reference: http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2007/11/04/model-view-presenter-mvp-design-pattern-close-look-part-2-passive-view.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say what you have there is more akin to MVP (Model-View-Presenter) than MVC. There are two main varieties of MVP...Supervising Controller and Passive View. What you have here seems closest to Passive View, which is a pretty classic MVP implementation that people use to improve and abstract WebForms. You can read more about an MVP implementation for WebForms here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/09/ASP.NETSupervisingControllerModelViewPresenterFromSchematicToUnitTestsToCode.aspx

The same general idea applies to Windows Forms too.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into Passive View. It has cropped up before so I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I'll vote something else.

The reason I say this is there is a ton of debate on what MVC is.

See [What's a controller anyway?](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhatsaControllerAnyway)

Comment: Ok, I'll change it to as a variation or type of MVC.

Answer (score 1):

While that is an implementation of MVC you have there, it isn't using the [one Microsoft made and recently released](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).  [Overview of it](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx) from Scott Gutherie if you want some history.  Some may call it MVP where instead of a Controller, that part is called a Presenter that handles business logic and user interaction generally.